# OpenCV Rect structure for marking sub-image

Tags: opencv

I'm looking at some code and i don't understand this line. can someone explain what it is doing?

```
smallImg = image( Rect(0, Slice_row, image.cols, 6) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`smallImg` is a sub-image/portion of the larger `image`.

This `smallImg` is formed using a [`cv::Rect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html), which is an object that describes a rectangular region in the `image`. This rectangular region is defined by the top-left coordinates, the width, and height of the rectangle. So here, `(0, Slice_row)` is the top left corner of the rectangle, `image.cols` is the width and `6` is the height.

So `smallImg` is a portion of `image` with the same width as the original  `image` but only having 6 rows of pixels starting from `Slice_row`.

Hope this helps